# how to avoid some function in the legend?

Tags: matplotlib

I need to include a line into a figure every time a button is clicked (I'm using pyqt4), this line has to be labeled and I also need to compare these lines with a constant function. Here is what I've tried:

```
labels = []
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='white')
ax.hold(True)

def function(k):
   x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
   y = np.sin(k * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x)
   labels.append('k = {}'.format(k))
   ax.plot(x, y)
   # reference line
   plt.axhline(y=0.1, c='k', linestyle='--')
   plt.legend(labels)

for i in range(0,5):
   function(i)

plt.show()
```

The result:
[image]

There is a simple way to skip the constant line marker in the legend frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm not following but it doesn't look like your reference line `axhline(y=0.1, ...)` is included in the legend.

I would set this separately, no reason to redraw it every time you plot a new line. Also try passing the `label` inside the `plot` function

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='white')
ax.hold(True)
# reference line - only draw this once
plt.axhline(y=0.1, c='k', linestyle='--')

def function(k):
   x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
   y = np.sin(k * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x)
   ax.plot(x, y, linestyle='-', label='k = {}'.format(k)) # set label attribute for line

for i in range(0,5):
   function(i)

plt.legend() # you only need to call this once, it will generate based on the label assigned to line objects
plt.show()
```

**Note:** If you want to do this interactively (i.e. draw on a button press) then you'll have to call `plt.legend()` upfront and call `plt.draw()` after each new line is added, that way it'll update the legend.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear in my question, but your answer fixed the problem and gave me a tip to improve other plotting functions of my project. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there are actually 10 lines in your plot but your legend only shows 5 labels. If you check this by putting the label in the `plot` and `axhline` commands like this.

```
def function(k):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
    y = np.sin(k * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x)
    ax.plot(x, y, label='k = {}'.format(k))
    # reference line
    ax.axhline(y=0.1, c='k', linestyle='--', label='reference')
    ax.legend()
    print "number of lines in plot: {}".format(len(ax.lines))
```

Because you set the [Axes.hold property](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/api/axes_api.html?highlight=hold#matplotlib.axes.Axes.hold) to True, the Axes is not cleared, but a new line is added to Axes object every time you call these commands. This may be faster but you have to be careful to avoid adding duplicate artists. A simple solution would be to split the drawing in two functions: one to create an empty plot and one to add a line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def init_plot(ax):
    ax.hold(True)
    ax.axhline(y=0.1, c='k', linestyle='--', label='reference')
    ax.legend()

def add_line(ax, k):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 100)
    y = np.sin(k * np.pi * x) * np.exp(-5 * x)
    ax.plot(x, y, label='k = {}'.format(k))
    ax.legend()    

def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='white')

    init_plot(ax)
    for i in range(0,5):
        add_line(ax, i)

    plt.show()
    #raw_input('please press enter\n') # for OS-X

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I recommend to read the [Artist tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html) and of course the [Legend guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).